# Is there a DPC++/SYCL equivalent of CUDA's atomicCAS?

Tags: atomic, compare-and-swap, intel-oneapi, sycl, oneapi

From my understanding, CUDA's `atomicCAS` has the following definition (this is one of the four)

```
int atomicCAS(int* address, int compare, int val);
```

and it compares atomically the values located at `address` (named in the doc `old`) in the global shared memory with `compare` and in case of equality assigns the value to `val`, otherwise does nothing. In both cases returns `old`.

Looking at SYCL API, I can only find `compare_exchange_strong` which, unfortunately, does not do what I'm looking for as, using the same naming as above, it compares `old` with `compare` and if not successful, alters `compare` (which is passed by reference).

Comment: Yes, C++ [`std::atomic`'s `compare_exchange_strong`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) updates `expected` by reference, but it's intended to be a local variable.  The update of that output arg is *not* atomic.  It's just a different way of exposing the same underlying primitive operation, an atomic CAS.  Changing code to use it is purely a matter of declaring local variables.  If the compare was true, then `compare` is already equal to the `old` value, so not update of it is necessary. IDK if that's why you thought it was different or a problem for your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Peter Cordes noted in a comment, `sycl::compare_exchange_strong` is the right choice. From the SYCL 2020 rev. 4 description of `compare_exchange_strong`:

> Atomically compares the value of the object referenced by this `atomic_ref` against the value of `expected`. If the values are equal, replaces the value of the referenced object with the value of `desired`; otherwise assigns the original value of the referenced object to `expected`.

So,

```cpp
int old = compare;
ref.compare_exchange_strong(old, val);
```

is, in terms of updating `ref`, equivalent to

```cpp
old = atomicCAS(address, compare, val);
```

If you are interested, you can [see for yourself how hipSYCL implements `sycl::compare_exchange_strong`](https://github.com/illuhad/hipSYCL/blob/f0983b25d33b8de61b170c9d2cfca876fe73c3c9/include/hipSYCL/sycl/libkernel/generic/hiplike/atomic_builtins.hpp#L177).